# net6 Use in-memory db for unit tests

Tags: c#, .net-core

I got a small app that is using EF6 to access database.

Im confusing the DbContext when the app starts:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<PlayersContext>(o => o.UseNpgsql(dbString));
```

Ive created a test app class to setup my test cases, to stub services etc:

```
  public class TestApp : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
    protected override IHost CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.RemoveAll(typeof(IAuthService));
            services.AddScoped<IAuthService, StubAuthService>();
        });
        return base.CreateHost(builder);
    }
}
```

Im trying to do something similar to stub my database with the in-memory database.

```
 public class TestApp : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
    protected override IHost CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.RemoveAll(typeof(IAuthService));
            services.AddScoped<IAuthService, StubAuthService>();
            var myDatabaseName = "test_"+DateTime.Now.ToFileTimeUtc();
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<PlayersContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: myDatabaseName )
                .Options;
            services.AddDbContextFactory<PlayersContext>(f => new DbContext(options));
        });
        return base.CreateHost(builder);
    }
}
```

But I cannot access this db. I wanted to get the PlayersContext instance but using the in-memory provider so I can setup some players while also making sure inside the services this in-memory provider will be used. Any lights on what I might be doing wrong here ?

Comment: I cant understand the problem. what happen when you get injected dbcontext?

Comment: The question is how do I get this injected context.

Comment: Did you solve this?